# Are equity prices and stock prices the same?

Tags: stock-market

Do we use in common language "equity price" as a synonym to "stock price"?

Comment: Someone might wish to consult a dictionary to get something more definitive, but from my experience in writing financial commentary, they are interchanged based on personal preference or style, at least in North America. U.K. usage might be different.

Answer (score 1):

[Stocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock):

> Stock (also capital stock) is all of the shares into which ownership of a corporation is divided

[Equity](http://n%20finance,%20equity%20is%20ownership%20of%20assets%20that%20may%20have%20debts%20or%20other%20liabilities%20attached%20to%20them.%20Equity%20is%20measured%20for%20accounting%20purposes%20by%20subtracting%20liabilities%20from%20the%20value%20of%20the%20assets):

> In finance, equity is ownership of assets that may have debts or other liabilities attached to them. Equity is measured for accounting purposes by subtracting liabilities from the value of the assets

Answer (score 0):

Equity is simply describing the ownership of an asset. Stocks are one form of equity, since they represent fractional ownership of a firm, and equity also expands to any other asset as person can own. Because of this stock prices are a subset of equity prices.